# VisualWorks Smalltalk - can't access parent's methods

Tags: oop, inheritance, methods, smalltalk, visualworks

I have a problem with class inheritage - I have two classes defined like this:

```
Smalltalk defineClass: #Field
superclass: #{Core.Object}
indexedType: #none
private: false
instanceVariableNames: 'name type '
classInstanceVariableNames: ''
imports: ''
category: ''
```

and

```
Smalltalk defineClass: #CheckBox
superclass: #{Smalltalk.Field}
indexedType: #none
private: false
instanceVariableNames: 'checked '
classInstanceVariableNames: ''
imports: ''
category: ''
```

in class 'Field' I have a method setName:

```
setName: n
name := n.
^n
```

It works perfectly fine for something like this:

```
|tmp|
tmp := Field new.
tmp setName: 'fancy name'.
```

, but when I change 'Field' to 'CheckBox' in the above example I always get "Unhandled Exception: MessageNotUnderstood: #setName: ". Do you guys know how am I supposed to make my subclass inherit a setName: method from it's parent? I'm trying to find an answer everywhere, but no luck so far.

EDIT:
Full error message is:
[image: Error message #1]
[image: Error message #2]

Comment: Can you relay the full message for the message not understood error? I'd like to know what object it thinks doesn't understand setName:. On the surface it looks like it should work.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking. I've added EDIT with full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's anwser to my question: I'm stupid. I was messing around with my CheckBox initialize method and accidently deleted ^self line at the end. After putting it back there everything works fine. Thanks for your help, David, and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't explain the symptoms you were seeing.  Methods return self by default.  I suspect you closed the workspace that had a CheckBox variable defined as nil then ran the code in a new workspace.  In any case, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow your CheckBox class didn't get compiled. Check the spelling.  Make sure that there's no existing class called CheckBox. Make sure you can see the CheckBox class in your browser.

Comment: It is. I mean - when i fire up a debugger, I can see how it's getting initialized and how it's calling Field's 'initialize' method. And after that, when it comes to 'setName:' it all fails. The CheckBox class is the only such class in browser. However, I found out that under 'Instance Variable' after selecting 'name' there is nothing listed on the right pane, and when I select Field -> Instance variable -> name I see setName: method. Maybe that's somehow connected with the problem?

Comment: For the CheckBox class, you will see nothing in the right hand pane when you select "name" in the instance variable tab because CheckBox doesn't have any methods that reference name.  It should inherit those methods from Field.

Answer (score 0):

Just on a lark - in your workspace window, go to the Variables tab and make sure you don't have a variable called CheckBox.  If so, delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the #initialize method on your Checkbox class,
but it was, for some reason, answering nil.

When you changed the last line, so it would answer self,
you also changed whatever had been causing the method to answer nil.

Removing the line that was answering nil
would also have worked.

You can avoid this problem If you write your #new methods like this -

```
  >>new
      ^self basicNew
          initialize
          ; yourself
```

so you'll always get the new instance,
instead of like this --

```
  >>new
      ^super new initialize
```

whereby you always get whatever it is that
the #initialize method happens to answer.